# SEO in Flutter and NextJS

Tags: flutter, next.js, seo

I am really struggle in Flutter SEO.

According to this article, SEO is not good in Flutter
https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/faq#search-engine-optimization-seo

I am thinking if the following approach could help on Flutter SEO

1. I run flutter application in web, e.g. https://my-flutter-application.com
2. I create a SSR application using NextJS and handle incoming traffic, e.g. https://my-nextjs-ssr-web.com
3. Render a HTML with suitable content in `<title>` `<meta>` tags, and embed `iframe` to the Flutter application

So, basically, I use HTML to render `<head>` and `<meta>`; use `<iframe>` in body

I know it is not perfect, but I guess it is better than just using pure Flutter for SEO?

Thank you.